# Tkinter: Message label not updating

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

So I have a message label in my GUI that displays info from my database.

```
history_msg = StringVar()
history_msg.set("Oil change: {} \nTire Rotation: {} \nSpark Plugs: {}".format(last_recorded_oil_change, last_recorded_tire_rotation, last_recorded_spark_plugs))
```

last_recorded_oil_change, last_recorded_tire_rotation, last_recorded_spark_plugs are created and set equal to the mileage recorded for each maintenance in the database, with the code below (which is ran before the message)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT mileage FROM miles_log WHERE maintenance_type = 'Oil Change' ORDER BY maintenance_type")
last_recorded_oil_change = cursor.fetchone()
last_recorded_oil_change = last_recorded_oil_change[0]
cursor.execute("SELECT mileage FROM miles_log WHERE maintenance_type = 'Tire Rotation' ORDER BY maintenance_type")
last_recorded_tire_rotation = cursor.fetchone()
last_recorded_tire_rotation = last_recorded_tire_rotation[0]
cursor.execute("SELECT mileage FROM miles_log WHERE maintenance_type = 'Spark Plugs' ORDER BY maintenance_type")
last_recorded_spark_plugs = cursor.fetchone()
last_recorded_spark_plugs = last_recorded_spark_plugs[0]
```

Now I have a function named update_oil_change() that is called when I click a button. It reads input from entry box, converts it to an int, then uses cursor execute to update the database with the input. This is the function:

```
def update_oil_change():
    oil_change_miles_entered = IntVar()
    oil_change_miles_entered = last_miles_entry.get()
    oil_change_miles_entered = int(oil_change_miles_entered)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE miles_log SET mileage = '{}' WHERE maintenance_type = 'Oil Change'".format(oil_change_miles_entered))
    conn.commit()
    print("Oil Change updated to: {}".format(oil_change_miles_entered))
```

My issue is that, when I type the mileage (for example, 5000) into the entry box and click the button, the message widget doesnt update and show 5000. I have to close the GUI, rerun it, and then it shows. I know the function is being called successfully because it's also printing to the terminal. Shouldn't the program keep looping around, calling the following code, updating the variables with the new contents of the database, with the contents of the message reflecting the newly updated variables?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT mileage FROM miles_log WHERE maintenance_type = 'Tire Rotation' ORDER BY maintenance_type")
last_recorded_tire_rotation = cursor.fetchone()
last_recorded_tire_rotation = last_recorded_tire_rotation[0]
cursor.execute("SELECT mileage FROM miles_log WHERE maintenance_type = 'Spark Plugs' ORDER BY maintenance_type")
last_recorded_spark_plugs = cursor.fetchone()
last_recorded_spark_plugs = last_recorded_spark_plugs[0]
```

this is my first ever program so I hope my code is readable and my question makes sense

Comment: You need to update `history_msg` as well if it is linked to the message label.

Comment: @acw1668 I'm not understanding. When it loops around shouldn't it update automatically?

Comment: Why do you think that `history_msg` will be updated automatically when the three `last_recorded_xxxx` are updated?

Comment: @acw1668 because isn't a GUI just a big never ending loop??? if the three variables get updated later in the loop, when it loops again shouldnt the message show with the newly updated variables

Comment: No you still need to update `history_msg` using the three `last_recorded_xxxx`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you. do you mind explaining how I do this? I've tried a couple things with no success.

Comment: Just update `history_msg` inside those functions that update the three `last_recorded_xxx`.